# How to execute .sh file in Cocoa App

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I am new in cocoa app development. I have upgrade.sh file which I have to execute in my Cocoa app.

I have already tried to run the file in terminal using below command & it's working fine

```
ZeMacTest:Demo ZTech$ sh upgrade.sh -d
```

Can any one suggest how to execute the .sh extension file in Cocoa app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh" arguments:@[@"upgrade.sh", @"-d"]];
```

Comment: I am getting  exception [General] An uncaught exception was raised. launch path not accessible

Comment: you are sandboxed? then that won't work -- ever -- no way

Comment: you would need to sign you task and ship the script with your app.. it'll be painful :D

Comment: it is /bin/sh on newer osxs my bad

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly after editing. Can you please assist me how to handle user input from .sh file? .sh file command check for the password, if does not exist then it asks for the password entry in the log. I want to provide input from my app UI.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use NSTask

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/path/to/script/sh"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yourScript.sh", nil]];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

[task launch];
[task release];
```

Comment: whats are the unused pipes for ;)

Comment: @yogesh I am getting execption An uncaught exception was raised. Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8

Comment: You need to use setLaunchPath like this:
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
Then use setArguments for your script:
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"~/connect.sh", nil]];